# Add color array to vtkImageData C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vtk

I'm newbie at VTK and I'm trying to understand the basics.

Let's suppose that I need to display three dimensional structured data (vtkImageData) which has: `nx = 10, ny = 10, nz = 10` where nx/ny/nz - number of points along each dimension. For each point (x,y,z) I have a value `val(x,y,z)`. So the color of each node is defined by the `val`.
As I know in C++ I would write:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Create an image data
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();

// Specify the size of the image data
int nx = 10;
int ny = 10;
int nz = 10;
imageData->SetDimensions(nx,ny,nz);
imageData->SetSpacing(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
imageData->SetOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

double val[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    data[i] = i;
}

// after that I need to set val-array as color for imageData object

return 0;
}
```

How to set `val[1000]` array to `imageData` so the color of each node to be defined by the `val`?
P.S. I've seen some examples from VTK web site but still didn't solve the problem

Best regards,

kerim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Create an image data
vtkNew<vtkImageData> imageData;

// Specify the size of the image data
int nx = 10;
int ny = 10;
int nz = 10;
imageData->SetDimensions(nx,ny,nz);
imageData->SetSpacing(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
imageData->SetOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> array;
array->SetName("Name");
double val[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    array->InsertNextValue(i);
}

image->GetPointData()->AddArray(array);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I started to learn `vtkStructuredGrid` and I can't make it to be displayed with colors defined by `vtkFloatArray`. For `vtkImageData` I could display it with colors given by `vtkLookupTable` (setup `vtkLookupTable`, use `vtkImageMapToColors`, and link it with `vtkLookupTable` and finally `actor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(vtkImageMapToColors->GetOutputPort());`).Could you please give me some hint how to create colored `vtkStructuredGrid`?

Comment: open another question.